# What does "/^\s*$/" mean in this javascript?

Tags: javascript, pdf, foxit

I have this javascript that works well in my PDF form to set a field as required if another field contains data.  However, I want to have it ignore a value of "0.00" for the test.  But I do not know what `/^\s*$/` means let alone how to alter the script for my condition.

```
var rgEmptyTest = /^\s*$/;
// t is the value to be tested and f is the field to set accordingly
function testMyField (t, f) {
if (rgEmptyTest.test(t)) {
this.getField(f).required = false;         
} else {
this.getField(f).required = true;         
}
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: https://regexr.com/3rf9u

Comment: @j08691 This is a great resource!  Thank you for sharing. Any ideas on how to exclude '0.00'?  I thought maybe '/^\s*(0.00)$/' but I am not sure that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

**In your piece of code there is a function that uses regex**

A [javaScript regExp reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) for you.

Thanks [@j08691](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616443/j08691) for the link that explains and let you test the regex used ([regexr.com/3rf9u](https://regexr.com/3rf9u)).

**You can change your code like this to make a logical exception**

```
var rgEmptyTest = /^\s*$/;
var rgTest = /0.00/;
// t is the value to be tested and f is the field to set accordingly
function testMyField (t, f) {
  if (rgEmptyTest.test(t) || rgTest.test(t)) {
    this.getField(f).required = false;         
  } else {
    this.getField(f).required = true;         
  }
}
```

I guess it should work

Comment: This did not work, however, I am going to work with it and see if I can figure out why.

Comment: I am not having any luck :-(

Comment: `/0.00/` won't just match `0.00`, it will also match `10.00`, `20.00`, `100.00`, `1,000,000.00`, and so on

Answer (score 0):

\s means space
* Means any number
"  " This is empty
"     " This too

Answer (score 0):

I think I got this to work:

```
var rgEmptyTest = /^\s*$/;
var rgTest = /^[0\.00]$/;
// t is the value to be tested and f is the field to set accordingly
function testMyField (t, f) {
if (rgEmptyTest.test(t) || rgTest.test(t)) {
this.getField(f).required = false;         
} else {
this.getField(f).required = true;         
}
}
```

Thank you @Higor Lorenzon and @j08691!

Comment: `^[0\.00]$` does not work the way you think. It tests for a single character `0` *or* `.` (which is unnecessarily escaped as it is inside a character class). Even if you explicitly test for `^0.00$` it will *only* match that exact string, but not `0.0` or, indeed, plain `0`. Parse the string to a number and test if it's zero, done.

Comment: @usr2564301 The field's default value is '0.00' which is why I need to exclude it explicitly,  the field value can never be '0' as it is a calculated field with answers to two decimal places.  But I thought I had tried '^0.00$' but I will try it again. Thank you for the feedback, I am very grateful.

Comment: Apologies – for a real *exact* test you need `^0\.00$`, because the `.` character is special when not escaped.